# Meteor CPU load: Method call vs Subscription

Tags: meteor

What is the CPU costless between sending data to a client via publish/subscription and via Method calls?

Comment: Since the method call is a one-shot, and the subscription can do more actions over time, the method call would be the lightest... Without more information however, I fear no good answer can be given.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is going to assume that you simply want to send data to the client:

It depends on what you want to do. If you want realtime updates the subscriptions model is ideal when compares to call a server method each 5 seconds or so.

When you don't want reactive updates, simply pass the flag `reactive:false` in your find() query.

Methods are used when you want, for example, to return the results on an aggregation (because meteor doesn't support reactivity for aggregations), to get updates for unsupported operator ($where is not supported yet), etc.

Usually the bottlenecks exists in the application design/architecture.